# Sort typescript suggestions by declaration (instead of alphabetical)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to get typescript key suggestions in the order they were declared, as opposed to alphabetical?

If I have a string enum:

```
export enum Fruits {
    PEARS = "PEARS",
    APPLES = "APPLES",
    PEACHES = "PEACHES",
    BANANAS = "BANANAS"
}
```

My intellisense suggestions for `Fruits.` appear as:

```
APPLES
BANANAS
PEACHES
PEARS
```

It's trivial but I like to destructure my objects and have to frequently reorder them to preserve my sense of structure.

Some meaningful examples:

```
export enum StatusA {
    start = 'start',
    finish = 'finish',
}
```

Suggests:

```
finish
start
```

And

```
type Item = {
    id;
    name;
    title;
    description;
    anOptionalField?;
    theLeastUsedField?;
}
```

Suggests

```
anOptionalField
description
id
name
theLeastUsedField
title
```

Comment: I'm trying to think of a reason this could possibly be useful

Comment: Compare `enum Status {start = 'start', finish = 'finish'}` and `enum Status {finish = 'finish', start = 'start'}`

Comment: Add sort attribute and give the value as you need to order

Comment: @Kevin I agree it's trivial, but it would improve my workflow. I tend to destructure an object at the top of a function and use its properties in the order I declared them. By preserving its declared shape in my suggestions I could unpack its props in the order I need them one-by-one with a quick tab, as if spring-loaded, instead of either hunting each one down specifically or filling my block with unused variables (which can trigger warnings depending on your lint rules)

Comment: @AdamNorman I'm looking to adjust the intellisense settings rather than recombine the data